# Creating a dynamic list of DIVs with D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, d3.js

I have been using [D3](http://d3js.org) to create fancy animated charts, and the examples are great. However, I'm trying to do something seemingly a lot more basic, and having trouble - binding data to a simple list of DIVs.

I set up `enter()` to initialize elements at opacity 0, `transition()` to fade them in, and `exit()` to fade them out and remove them. `enter()` and `exit()` seem to be working fine - however, when an update contains an existing element already in the list, it seems to get partially removed - the containing DIV remains, but the contents disappear. I can't understand why the contents of the element would get changed in this way.

My code is as follows:

```
var data = [...];
sorted = data.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.descending(a.id, b.id); });

var tweet = tweetsBox
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(sorted, function(d) { return d.id; });

var enterDiv = tweet.enter()
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tweetdiv")
    .style("opacity", 0);
enterDiv.append("div")
    .attr("class", "username")
    .text(function(d) { return "@" + d.username });
enterDiv.append("div")
    .attr("class", "displayname")
    .text(function(d) { return d.displayname });
enterDiv.append("div")
    .attr("class", "date")
    .text(function(d) { return d.date });
enterDiv.append("div")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.text });

tweet.transition()
    .delay(200)
    .style("opacity", 1);

tweet.exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove();
```

I also set up [a jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rWByD/1/) demonstrating the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're selecting the `div`s you created, but create more than one `div` per data element. When updating, d3 tries to match the data to the nested `div`s. As you're already assigning a special class to the top-level `div`s, the fix is very simple. Replace

```
.selectAll('div')
```

with

```
.selectAll('.tweetdiv')
```