# D3.js nested data joins on HTML lists and sub-lists

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, jquery-selectors, html-lists

This Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kaxjL3La/ shows my attempt to adapt the D3 [general update pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) to using nested `<ul><li>` HTML lists. I believe what complicates this situation is that I'm seeking to use the same tags in the outer and inner lists, unlike examples on the web with `tr/td` or `g/circle`.

Explaining the fiddle in words: I want a list of numbers to be placed in an unordered list, with each number having a child list with some derived values:

```
function update(arr) {
    var globalList = d3.select("#lst");

    var data = globalList.selectAll("li").data(arr, function(d) { return d; });
    data.exit().remove();
    var list = data.enter().append('li').text(
        function(d, i) { return "[" + i + "]=" + d; });
    var subList = list.selectAll("ul")
                      .data(function(d) { return [ d / 10, d / 100 ]; })
                      .enter()
                      .append("ul")
                      .append("li")
                      .text(function(d, i) { return "[" + i + "]=" + d; });
}
```

The first update (creation step) works fine, but subsequent calls to `update` result in the sub-lists disappearing for the update elements (numbers that are the same between calls to `update()`, i.e., 30). If you add a `console.log(data.exit())` before the `remove()` call, you see that the `selectAll("li").data(...)` call has matched the sub-lists, which will then be removed.

If I omit the `<li>` tags in the sub-lists, and just have a sequence of `<ul>` tags, as in `update2()`, then I do not lose the sub-lists on update. This is the correct behavior as far as my data join and data-driven display is concerned, but it is not good HTML to have a sequence of `<ul>` tags containing my list elements! I only showed this to confirm that, if the sublists consisted of tags that weren't captured by `selectAll()`, I get correct behavior.

My question is: how do I prevent D3's `selectAll` from recursing and finding all `<li>` descendants of the `globalList` selector so that I can use `<ul><li>` tags in the sub-lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438376/500207, I can accomplish this by assigning the outer list's `<li>` tags a custom CSS class, like `outer`, then calling `selectAll("li.outer")`.

```
function update(arr) {
    var globalList = d3.select("#lst");

                                    // v----v note 1 (of 2)
    var data = globalList.selectAll("li.outer").data(arr, function(d) { return d; });
    data.exit().remove();
    var list = data.enter().append('li').text(
        function(d, i) { return "[" + i + "]=" + d; })
                           .classed('outer', true); // <--- note 2 (of 2)
    var subList = list.selectAll("ul")
                      .data(function(d) { return [ d / 10, d / 100 ]; })
                      .enter()
                      .append("ul")
                      .append("li")
                      .text(function(d, i) { return "[" + i + "]=" + d; });
```

Is this really the best thing to do?